# Java Axis2 :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am going to create a sample axis 2 web service using two axis eclipse plugging s.First I wrote a very basic Helloworld service and then using the plugging (Service Archiver) I generated .aar file inside services folder. Then I generated the WSDL file using the plugin (Code Generator) and the WSDL and other classes (Stub and CallBackHandler) were generated successfully. But when executing the client there is a Error in below line.

```
HelloWorldStub helloWorldStub=new HelloWorldStub
SayHello sayHello=new sayHello()
sayHello.setMessage("Hi")
System.out.println(helloWorldStub.sayHello(sayHello).get_return())
```

When making a instance of the stub it generates below Error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/AxisFault
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have set the classpath to the java folder. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Class not found `org/apache/axis2/AxisFault `. it means missing jar in classpath . refer link http://findjar.com/class/org/apache/axis2/AxisFault.html

Comment: But I added all the jars provided by the axis2 1.6.2 run time and added them to the build path